# Custom MKOverlayView being clipped due to small MKMapRect

Tags: ios, mapkit

I'm implementing a custom `MKOverlayView`. Everything seems to be going fine until I zoom in on my overlay.

What I've found is that the mapRect given to me in `- (void)drawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale inContext:(CGContextRef)context` seems arbitrarily restrictive, but only vertically. It clips my image on top and bottom until I zoom out again. I've filled the `mapRect` to see what portion the map thinks I need to redraw, and I don't understand why it's so small.

Comment: I think maps are tiled, so it may be calling drawMapRect multiple times - one per tile.

Comment: this is true, but if I draw each requested tile, I see that they still don't fill all space I'd expect.

Comment: What happens if you ignore the incoming `mapRect` and just draw the entire overlay every time this is called?

Comment: If you change your `drawMapRect` to fill the rect with a solid colour, what does the map look like when it's all done?

Comment: Matt: I am drawing the entire overlay each time. It seems the drawing is only applied to the mapRect it gives you.